# How can I parse an XML file from the command line (for GeekTool)?

Tags: terminal, xml, parsing

I'd like to find a Terminal command that can pull the file at  http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.xml?screen_name=SOMEUSERNAME&count=1 and parse it to find a user's Twitter status.  The status is inside the "statuses -> status -> text" location on the tree.

I've looked into libxml and xmllint.  I think I'm on the right track with xmllint, but I'm not sure.  With xmllint, I know I could do `xmllint --shell file.xml` and then `cat //statuses/status/text`.  But, I'd prefer to be able to do some type of command like *CURL* | *XMLLINT* | *SED* that would download the file, parse it, and return the status in one fell swoop.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-tipclp/index.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perl's XML::Twig comes with...

```
xml_grep --nowrap --text_only /statuses/status/text
```

In XML::XPath you can do:

```
perl -MXML::XPath -E 'my $xp = XML::XPath->new(ioref => \*STDIN); say $xp->getNodeText("/statuses/status/text");'
```

or

```
perl -MXML::XPath -E 'my $xp = XML::XPath->new(ioref => \*STDIN); for my $node ($xp->find("/statuses/status/text")->get_nodelist) { say $node->string_value; }'
```

(Of course, there's [Net::Twitter](http://search.cpan.org/~mmims/Net-Twitter-3.17001/lib/Net/Twitter.pod) too.)

Comment: I've found Net::Twitter::Lite easier to work with for simple stuff